# How to show that $\frac{z-a}{a-z}$ has not inverse?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

How to show that $\frac{z-a}{a-z}$ has not inverse?

I know that $$\frac{z-a}{a-z}=\frac{-1(a-z)}{a-z}=-1 .$$ 
But state if I'm wrong, that following is true: $$f(z)=\frac{z-a}{a-z} \Leftrightarrow (a-z)w=z-a \Leftrightarrow \cdots a=z \Rightarrow f^{-1}(z)=a.$$ But now $(f \circ f^{-1})(z)=f(a)=\frac{0}{0} \neq z$( not defined). So where is error in my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse as a function or as a number?  As you say, for $z \ne a$, this is $-1$, which has $-1$ as a fine inverse.  As a function, it is not injective, so you can't invert it.

Answer (score 4):

For instance, 
$$
f(a+1)=f(a+2)=-1.
$$
So your function is not injective.

Hence it can't have an inverse.

Well, I believe you meant inverse with respect to composition $\circ$, and not product.

Answer (score 0):

The $\dots$. What happened there? Divided by $w+1$? But this is $0$ by the above calculation.

However, to show that it doesn't have an inverse, it is enough to show up $2$ values of $z$ that gives the same result. Now if $z_1,z_2$ are different from $a$, the result will be defined and $-1$.